# Graph API list of application inside a collection

Tags: azure, graph

Hi I would like to use the graph api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

To gather name, icon and link of all the application of a user.
The application are inside a collection.
How can I get via API only applications inside a collection?

Comment: I am also wondering if any application collection actions are available over Graph API